# Is splice a part of POSIX?

Tags: c, posix, splice

I can only use POSIX standard library functions. I want to use `splice` function. Is it POSIX or not? How can I find out?

Comment: Search https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/. Splice isn't POSIX. The requirement of _GNU_SOURCE listed in the manpage also gives a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check man-pages:

```
$ man splice
```

It [says](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html):

```
CONFORMING TO
       This system call is Linux-specific.
```

So it is not in POSIX.